# I am trying to get the drop down menu items dynamiclly from the database using SQL

Tags: sql, forms, jsp, web-applications, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get the drop down menu items dynamically from the database using SQL statement
so far, i am only getting empty items
this is the code am using

```
  <FORM ACTION="display.jsp">
              <label>Semester:
                <select name="semester_form">
                 <option selected="semester">Semester Select</option> 
                 <%
                  ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select semester_name from semester_schedule_reader ");

                  while(rs2.next())
                    {   %>
                     <option value='<%rs2.getString(1);%>'></option>

                    <%  
                    }
                 %>
```

i was able to print out results using the same select statement, but am trying to display them in the drop down menu.

Comment: `selected="semester"` is not html. `selected` should only be empty or have the value "selected" (for the option that you want to be selected). Also you may want to have something visible so: `<%String val = rs2.getString(1);%> <option value='<%=val%>'><%=val%></option>`

Comment: i have tried the following and it worked <%
         ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select * from semester_schedule_reader ");
         
         while(rs2.next())
           { %>
            <option> <%=rs2.getString(4)%></option>
             
         
           <% 
           }
        %>

Comment: the first query should work as well as long as you have the column `semester_name` in that table

Answer (score 0):

you have to use
               <%=rs2.getString(1)%>

Do not use semicolon after that. Its not a scriptlet its, expression which is evaluated at runtime.